# Knockout JS. Update the observable array's object

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to Knockout and my requirement is,whenever an object property of an observable array changes its value programmatically, the UI should update accordingly. But it doesn't seems to work for me.

I am aware that, for this to work the object property needs to be an observable itself. And I am making it observable, but somehow its not updating UI.
I tried same on normal field of a model and it works.

Can anyone please suggest on what I am missing ?

```
var appViewModel = function() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable("Amit");
        this.Books = ko.observableArray(Books);
        this.updateBook = function() {
            this.Books()[0].Book = ko.observable(this.Books()[0].Book);
            this.firstName("Goda");
            this.Books()[0].Book("Harry Potter and Prisoner of Azkaban");
        }
    };
```

I have my complete code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AmitGoda/jVQY8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to make the book observable after you've bound the data.

You want to recursively make `Books` observable. This can be done with the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html):

```
this.Books = ko.mapping.fromJS(Books);
```

This way you can simply do the following in `updateBook`:

```
this.firstName("Goda");
this.Books()[0].Book("Harry Potter and Prisoner of Azkaban");
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/jVQY8/1/

**Edit:**

To revert the changes you could simple keep track of the original data:

```
var initialData = Books;
```

Then use the mapping plugin again to revert the changes:

```
self.revert = function() {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData, self.Books);
};
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/jVQY8/2/

For a more advanced solution where you can commit / reset the value, see the following post:
http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html

Comment: Superb! That works like a charm. This is what I was looking for. And thanks a lot to point me towards the mapping plugin. My intention was to make each property as observable. I have one more question, I want to subscribe beforChange event for all the author properties, so when it changes I can store the old value in a temp array and if user click "Revert" button in my UI, I would call a function to iterate the temp array and get the old value of the row and update UI accordingly..

Comment: I added an example to my answer.

Comment: Your example looks clean. And I have already gone through the link suggested by you. Actually in My UI for each row there will be a revert button and user can click on particular button to revert that row. But the example you gave and the code provided in the link reloads the entire model with previous data and that's where I thought about temp array to track the change for each row and UI respects that. But I am stuck.